# Pytest creating temp CSV file to read from

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pytest

I have some code that parses a csv for some certain values based on an id number passed in. In the sake of testing I would like to create dummy data files for CSV using pytest.

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    return Client('FOO, BAR', 98763, 1986, '08/19/91', 'MALE')

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def file_name(tmpdir_factory):
    fn = tmpdir_factory.mktemp('data'.join('csvNg.csv'))
    headers = ['NAME','PN','MRN','DOB','GENDER']
    with open(fn,'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.Dict(csvfile,fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'NAME': 'FOO, BAR', 'PN': 98763, 'MRN': 1986, 
            'DOB': '08/19/91', 'GENDER': 'MALE' })
    return str(fn)

def test_locate_ngen():
    FOOBAR = client()
    assert locate_ngen(1986,file_name) == FOOBAR
```

Current error I am getting when running:

> @pytest.fixture(scope='session') E    IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is
>   a directory:
>   '/private/var/folders/mn/xg5s_2rd5tbd9hs_ckgwzvtmkqnwq5/T/pytest-of-ronswanson/pytest-4/cdatasdatavdataNdatagdata.datacdatasdatav0'

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And try to avoid CAPS. ;0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fn = tmpdir_factory.mktemp('data').join('csvNg.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like like when i return the filename it is coming back as function. I must not be using fixtures correctly. Here the error I am seeing.

def locate_ngen(mrnTolocate,fn):
     if not validate_input(mrnTolocate):
      return False
     headers = ['NAME','PN','MRN','DOB','GENDER']
>    with open(fn) as csvFile:
E    TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not function

Comment: `with open(str(fn),'w') as csvfile:`